# In ReactJS, is it true that we can do some proof of concept work just using useEffect() and useState()? Any alternative to useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I was stunned when a phone interview person asked me to fetch data and do some nice formatting on the page, but have to add all the boilerplates of Redux and `redux-thunk` by memorization.

But later on, I found that, isn't it true that for proof of concept, just trying to get some data and format it nicely on screen, we can just use `useState()` and `useEffect()` and we can totally forget about Redux?

For example, all it takes is:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((d) => {
        setData(d);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre>
      <img src={data.thumbnailUrl} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lovelace-m3igx

and this is already a proof of concept. The Redux and all the boilerplate can just be added slowly (and I don't really memorizing them).

I think I'd probably use `useState()`, but what about `useEffect()`? Can something else be used?  The docs says `useEffect()` is for side effect, but it is not really a side effect item here.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Redux is just a state management library, you obviously don't need it to showcase your React knowledge. Did the interviewer ask you to use Redux? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: yes he asked me to use redux-thunk and wire everything up, like even the dispatch, action, reducer...

Comment: And you were supposed to do that from memory, without looking up the docs? Run from that interviewer and that company :)

Comment: @nonopolarity well it seems then they wanted to check your redux knowledge

Comment: @Konstantin yes, the interviewer said he knows my pain. He said he is a programmer himself but all they want to hire maybe somebody who can constantly type on the keyboard to whip out some code, even if it is somebody who didn't have a CS background but just went to a React / Redux bootcamp

Comment: @gmoniava yes, and when I said, it is just to dispatch some action so that the reducer will create a new state, for the components to use, he wouldn't take that but wanted all the code typed out verbatim

Comment: @nonopolarity In development we may always need to look things up.

Comment: @gmoniava I know... it is like a memorization game... like LeetCode and if I can't remember which of `call()` and `apply()` takes an array and which is comma separated, they may give the judgment the candidate is not good

Comment: so you can steer away from them....

Comment: So what is the problem here? Yes, you can build a great React app without any 3rd party library. You don't need to memorize any API to be a good developer.

Comment: Tech interviewers usually take a term from your CV and ask you about it. the idea behind this is to ask you to explain a certain topic you're supposed to be familiar with. he couldn't care less if you implement it the wrong way or don't know the exact syntax. I've been interviewed like this smore than once. by big coorps as well.

Comment: @Stavm no, we were doing it on https://codesandbox.io and from the sound of it, it seems if I don't add all the exact code and have it running, then it will be a no-go for them

Comment: there are many skills needed by developers. memorizing code is not one of them. the interviewer was overshooting and missed the point of the interview. keep sending CVs. this act was far from representing.

Comment: @nonopolarity according to your profile you must be a senior developer, how come you surprised with such interview

Comment: @DennisVash I may be wrong, but if you look closely at the answers you'll it's mostly about IT rather then development. which might explain it.

Comment: @DennisVash in the old days we want programmers who can think. Nowadays it is like "pragmatic" programmers. They ask you to recite a lot of things, and they are not related to how to think. So I remember every line, every file of those boilerplate, so then what? I am a good programmer now?

Answer (score 1):

> Any alternative to useEffect()?

I guess the question is around fetching data with React. You have such FAQ question in docs ["How can I do data fetching with Hooks?"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks).

And there is no alternative to `useEffect`, maybe `useLayoutEffect` but that a minor difference for data fetching.

> The docs says `useEffect()` is for side effect, but it is not really a side effect item here.

It also says it's for fetching.

> **What does useEffect do?** ... we could also **perform data fetching** or call some other imperative API.

Comment: the name itself `useEffect` is really cheesy. What effect? Are we filming a movie now?  It is more like `performTask()`... but somehow they use `useState()`, use this, use that. But the era of pragmatic programmers, it is the practical people, the Taurus (Mark Zuckerberg), Capricorn (Jeff Bezos).  The life motto of Taurus is "I have", which is `useState()` I guess? To have some states.  The life motto of Capricorn is "I use", which is all these `useEffect`, `useDispatch` etc I guess? It doesn't even look like programming any more but just configuring something